# What does celery daemonization mean?

Tags: celery, daemon

Can I know what does `celery daemonization` mean? Also, I would like to start running both celery worker and celery beat using single command. Anyway to do it (one way I can think of is using `supervisor` module for worker and beat and then writing the starting scripts for those in a separate `.sh` file and running that script..any other way?)

In other terms, I can start the worker and beat process as background process manually even..right? So, daemonization in celery just runs the processes as background processes or is there anything else?

Comment: Where are you seeing the term "celery daemonization"? Usually to daemonize a process means to run it in such a way that it's disconnected from the shell or other process it's run from.

Comment: @DanielH http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html